# Embedding ruby into HAML without flanking/preceding 'tags'

Tags: haml

My ruby code shows up (and renders as 'Hello World', which is what's in the database), when I type:

```
%p= @task.notes
```

But when I try it this way rails breaks (NoMethodError in Tasks#index):

```
%p= Some text before code @task.notes
```

When I try this it just shows me literally what I typed (Some text before code = @tasks.notes):

```
%p Some text before code = @task.notes
```

When I try this it also just shows me literally what I typed (Some text before code %= @task.notes):

```
%p Some text before code %= @task.notes
```

When I try this it once again just shows me literally what I typed (Some text before code =@task.notes):

```
%p Some text before code =@task.notes
```

But when I try this it works (Some text before code Hello World), but seems really odd that there is no way to just put the code in right next to the text:

```
%div
  Some text before code
  = @task.notes
```

But when I try this I get an error (Haml::SyntaxError in Tasks#index):

```
%div Some text before code
  = @task.notes
```

I don't understand the logic of what is going on here and why I'm being forced to incorporate all these apparently meaningless returns in order to just produce the code I want next to some text.  Can somebody fill me in on how I can just include some ruby code next to some text without having to incorporate all these carriage returns?  Or is this just the way Haml is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [interpolate](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_) the code:

```
-# No =
%p Some text before code #{@task.notes}
```